# Diff in days(month / year) - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model, relational

The question is how is it possible to get difference in days from before to today and **knowing this difference is happened in the past**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its **possible** to get difference in days from before to today, ***all you need is the dates***. for the example this is some check in and check out date diff.

```
// Params in date
public static function getDateDifference($check_in, $check_out)
    {
        $check_in = strtotime($check_in);
        $check_out = strtotime($check_out);
        $date_difference = $check_out - $check_in;
        $date_difference = round($date_difference / (60 * 60 * 24));
        return $date_difference;
    }
```

Comment: Is it your custom static function or laravel's carbon already have it?

Comment: Its my custom static function

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: You can create your Helper.php at app/Helpers/Helpers.php

Comment: In diffInDay we use the syntax like this now()->DiffInDays($date->toString())? So how is it possible to use it?

Comment: I'm not good at static using function give me some example, please.

Comment: Here the keyword "Laravel helper | How to create helper | Create custom helper function | Laravel 8 | Learning Points"

Find it at youtube, video by Learning Points.

But he didn't make it as Class Helpers so you have to custom some of his code. just PM me if you stuck somewhere

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give a try but by now I accept the answer because it makes sense